# How to retrieve values from arrays and check if they match

Tags: php

I am learning to program in php and I have a little problem.
I have two arrays:
Array A:

```
array(10){
           [0]: string(10) "2012-08-01"
           [1]: int 1
           [2]: string(10) "2012-08-03"
           [3]: int 1
           [4]: string(10) "2012-08-07"
           [5]: int 2
           [6]: string(10) "2012-08-09"
           [7]: int 2
           [8]: string(10) "2012-08-27"
           [9]: int 1
          }
```

Array B:

```
array(4){
          [0]: string(10) "2012-09-04"
          [1]: string(10) "2012-09-06"
          [2]: string(10) "2012-09-08"
          [3]: string(10) "2012-09-10"
        }
```

I want to check if the first element from Array A equals the first element from Array B, if it does then write second element (in this case `1`) from array A to an new Array C (one dimensional) else don't write anything in an array C and next check if element with index 2 from an array A equals second element `[1]: string(10) "2012-09-06"` from an array B if so the write fourth element (`[3]: int 1`) from an array A to an array C etc. so an array C would have int elements only.
If someone could help me out how to sort this out please I would be very happy

Comment: Nested loops would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to do it this way, you could do something like the following:

```
foreach($arrayB as $bRow)
{
    if(FALSE !== ($key = array_search($bRow, $arrayA))
    {
        $arrayC[] = $arrayA[$key+1];
    }
}
```

However, a string-indexed array would probably be better for Array A.  Use the following for the 3 examples below:

```
$arrayA = array("2012-08-01" => 1, "2012-08-03" => 1, "2012-08-07" => 2, "2012-08-09" => 2, "2012-08-27" => 1);
$arrayB = array("2012-09-04", "2012-09-06", "2012-09-08", "2012-09-10");
$arrayC = array();
```

If Array A always contains more elements than Array B (or the same number):

```
foreach($arrayA as $key=>$value)
{
    if(in_array($key, $arrayB))
    {
        $arrayC[] = $value;
    }
}
```

If Array B always contains more elements than Array A (or the same number):

```
foreach($arrayB as $bRow)
{
    if(isset($arrayA[$bRow]))
    {
        $arrayC[] = $arrayA[$bRow];
    }
}
```

If it is possible that sometimes Array A is longer and sometimes Array B is longer:

```
$matchedIndexes = array();

foreach($arrayA as $key=>$value)
{
    if(in_array($key, $arrayB))
    {
        $arrayC[] = $value;
        $matchedIndexes[] = $key;
    }
}

foreach($arrayB as $bRow)
{
    // Only add the entries that we did not already add when looping through $arrayA
    if(!in_array($key, $matchedIndexes) && isset($arrayA[$bRow]))
    {
        $arrayC[] = $arrayA[$bRow];
    }
}
```

Populating arrayC with zeros foreach entry in arrayA that does not have a match in arrayB:

```
foreach($arrayA as $key=>$value)
{
    if(in_array($key, $arrayB))
    {
        $arrayC[] = $value;
    }
    else
    {
        $arrayC[] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: and im just wondering how to make it with a multidimensional array you suggested ?

Comment: just last question to you: if for example `arrayC` will give me result of 2 values for example `2,2` , how would I put those values to match them with dates `"2012-08-07" => 2, "2012-08-09" => 2` - display them on position that it match date in `arrayA` and rest of new array fill with `0` something like `arrayC` would give me result: `0, 0, 2, 2, 0` if you know what I mean, how to achive it ?

Comment: @takeit I just added another example to my answer, which achieves what I think you are asking for (although I'm not exactly sure where you're going with it)

Comment: thank you so much, I am trying to do very simple stats chart using some JS library :) that's why I need data to be displayed like that, let'see if I will do it because I think I did it complicated way

Comment: Your example works fine but `arrayC` has not 'projection' to `arrayB` `but to arrayA`, I want it to be displayed vice versa :) like `arrayB` so if element from `arrayA` match element from `arrayB` write it to `arrayC` to the position that it match in `arrayB` for example if value `"2012-08-07" => 2` in `arrayA` match date `"2012-08-07"`which is on position 4th in `arrayB` I want it to be displayed in `arrayC` on 4th position, other elements would be `0` and size of `arrayC` would match size of `arrayB`

Comment: @takeit just change `$arrayA` to `$arrayB` in the `foreach` and `$arrayB` to `$arrayA` in the `in_array`

Comment: yes I did it before but when I do it `arrayC` will have only matched date from `arrayB` even if one element match there is on position -1 from matched element displayed another element..

Comment: Sorry dont read comment above, read this: yes I did it before but when I do it `arrayC` will have only matched element from `arrayB` not from `arrayA` even if one element match there is second one on position -1 from matched one so there are total 2 elements.. one is on proper position but second is useless in `arrayC`..

Comment: anyway I did it with `array_key_exists` but need to improve it to display in `arrayC` value of `arrayA` and not value of `arrayB`, thanks

Answer (score 1):

First thing, in A you have 5 pair of elements and in B you have 4 elements. My code may produce error if you won't add element to $b. There will be one if statement needed, I'll write it if necessary. Assuming $b has 5 elements (from 0 to 4) this should work, but in your example array C will be empty, because there's no single match between dates in A and B:

```
$l=count($a); //$a is array A, $b is array B
$c=array(); //definition of empty array
for ($p=0;$p<$l;$p++) {
    if ($a[$p*2]==$b[$p]) 
        $c[]=$a[($p*2)+1]; // the way to add new element to C array is to use empty brackets
}
```